# Inconsistent moduleids in webpack

Tags: webpack, aurelia

I just switched an Aurelia app from SystemJS to Webpack. I got an error complaining about a moduleId the loader couldn't find. Digging into it I found that Webpack generated IDs in an inconsistent manner. While in general it's not important how moduleIds look like, here an error is caused by Aurelia expecting the IDs of the View (HTML) and the ViewModel (JS) to match. Usually, they do if you name them correctly. However, for some reason in this project Webpack generates inconsistent moduleIds for some View/ViewModel combinations. For example I get

```
contacts/persons/person-details and contacts/persons/person-details.html
```

for the JS and the HTML respectively, which is how it's supposed to be. But for a basically identical module I get

```
hriS and contacts/companies/company-details.html
```

or using `moduleIds: 'named'` (notice the leading `./src/` and trailing `.js`):

```
./src/contacts/companies/company-details.js and contacts/companies/company-details.html
```

**Why do I get the inconsistent IDs?** I don't know if this is an issue with Webpack itself of the [Aurelia loader plugin](https://github.com/aurelia/loader-webpack).

---

Workaround: You can force module IDs with Aurelia using `PLATFORM.moduleName()`. So for the example with Dialogs instead of using the ViewModel directly, you can do:

```
this.dialogService.open({ viewModel: PLATFORM.moduleName('contacts/companies/company-detail') });
```

Answer (score 0):

PLATFORM.moduleName is not an optional workaround, but a requirement.
If you look at webpack's section in aurelia guides (http://aurelia.io/docs/build-systems/webpack/a-basic-example#platformmodulename), you see:

```
From your application's perspective, there is also one important detail: 
each module reference must be wrapped in PLATFORM.moduleName(...).
This allows aurelia-loader-webpack to translate Aurelia's conventions
to something Webpack understands.
```

Hope this answers your question.

Best regards.

Comment: This is true for module references. If you create a dialog with Aurelia, you pass a ViewModel directly - which works for all Dialogs except one in my project.

Comment: Also in my other projects `PLATFORM.moduleName()` is not necessary.